# Why there's no `git flow hotfix fetch`?

Tags: git, git-flow

Working with a geographically dispersed dev team from time to time happens that a colleague prepares a `git flow hotfix` and publishes it for review (or because he has no grants to `finish` it).

When I `git pull` the repo I cannot fetch the hotfix in a proper way: the branch is present in the local repo but it isn't marked as an hotfix.

How can I execute correctly this work-flow?

Riccardo:

```
$ git pull
$ git flow hotfix start myhotfix
...
$ git commit -m "Fixed!" -a
$ git flow hotfix publish
```

Luca:

```
$ git pull
$ git flow hotfix
No hotfix branches exist.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *workflow* is:

Riccardo:

```
$ git pull
$ git flow hotfix start myhotfix
...
$ git commit -m "Fixed!" -a
$ git flow hotfix publish
```

Luca:

```
$ git pull
$ git flow hotfix
No hotfix branches exist.
$ git checkout hotfix/myhotfix
$ git flow hotfix
* myhotfix
$ git flow hotfix finish
```